# IE11 - Variable is out of range even though I used `let` for the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, null, undefined

The console stops on this line with the error:

```
Unable to get property 'srcset' of undefined or null reference

var srcObj = rollOverCollectionA[i].srcset.splice(171, 0, '-hover');
```

This above line is part of this section.

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
   var rollOverCollectionA = document.getElementById("roll-over-collection-b").getElementsByClassName("rollover");
   rollOverCollectionA = Array.prototype.slice.apply(rollOverCollectionA);
   console.log("rollOverCollectionA", rollOverCollectionA);
   var l = rollOverCollectionA.length;
   for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
     on("mouseover", "#" + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function () {
       var srcObj = rollOverCollectionA[i].srcset.splice(171, 0, '-hover');
       srcObj.splice(362, 0, 'hover-')
       rollOver(rollOverCollectionA[i].id, srcObj);
     });
     on("mouseout", "#" + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function () {
       // remove the hovers
       rollOut(rollOverCollectionA[i].id, rollOverCollectionA[i].srcset.replace('-hover', '').replace('hover-', ''));
     });
   }
 });
```

`i` is outside the range of the collection, but I used `let` for `i` as shown in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

What in IE is causing this? This works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari and Edge on Mac and PC.

Here's a runnable example:

```js
var on = function(event, elem, callback, capture) {
  console.log('elem in onFunction', elem);
  console.log('elem in onFunction', typeof elem);
  if (typeof elem === "function") {
    capture = callback;
    callback = elem;
    elem = window;
  }
  capture = !!capture;
  elem = typeof elem === "string" ? document.querySelector(elem) : elem;
  if (!elem) return;
  elem.addEventListener(event, callback, capture);
};

function rollOver(elem, src) {
  console.log('rollOver src', src);
  document.getElementById(elem).srcset = src;
}

function rollOut(elem, src) {
  console.log('rollOut src', src);
  document.getElementById(elem).srcset = src;
}
if (!String.prototype.splice) {
  /** * {JSDoc} * * The splice() method changes the content of a string by removing a range of * characters and/or adding new characters. * * @this {String} * @param {number} start Index at which to start changing the string. * @param {number} delCount An integer indicating the number of old chars to remove. * @param {string} newSubStr The String that is spliced in. * @return {string} A new string with the spliced substring. */
  String.prototype.splice = function(start, delCount, newSubStr) {
    return this.slice(0, start) + newSubStr + this.slice(start + Math.abs(delCount));
  };
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var rollOverCollectionA = document.getElementById("roll-over-collection-b").getElementsByClassName("rollover");
  rollOverCollectionA = Array.prototype.slice.apply(rollOverCollectionA);
  console.log("rollOverCollectionA", rollOverCollectionA);
  var l = rollOverCollectionA.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    on("mouseover", "#" + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function() {
      var srcObj = rollOverCollectionA[i].srcset.splice(171, 0, '-hover');
      srcObj.splice(362, 0, 'hover-')
      rollOver(rollOverCollectionA[i].id, srcObj);
    });
    on("mouseout", "#" + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function() {
      // remove the hovers
      rollOut(rollOverCollectionA[i].id, rollOverCollectionA[i].srcset.replace('-hover', '').replace('hover-', ''));
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.homepage-banner .offers-banner .button {
  background-color: #000;
}

.homepage-banner .offers-banner .button a {
  color: #fff;
}

.homepage-banner .offers-banner a {
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.homepage-banner .offers-banner {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  bottom: inherit;
  position: relative;
}

.homepage-banner .offers-banner h2 {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 34px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.homepage-banner .offers-banner p {
  font-family: termina, sans-serif;
  margin: 25px auto !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  /* font-size: 15px; */
}

.homepage-banner .offers-banner p:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* .homepage-banner .offers-banner a:hover {
      color: #000;
    } */

.homepage-banner .offers-banner .offer-banner-content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-flow: nowrap;
  align-self: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

.homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item .item-name {
  margin: 20px auto 0;
}

.homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item .item-name p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item:nth-of-type(2n) {
  margin: 0;
}

.homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item .item-name .button.button-helper {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  background-color: #e87ea6;
  border-color: #e87ea6;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: .23em 2em;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  outline: 0;
  font-family: termina, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  -webkit-font-kerning: none;
  -moz-font-kerning: none;
  font-kerning: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

div#roll-over-collection-b {
  position: absolute;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item {
    width: 30%;
  }
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item:nth-of-type(2n) {
    margin: 0 2em;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item:nth-of-type(2n) {
    margin: 0 3em;
  }
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item {
    width: 26%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner picture>img {
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: auto;
    line-height: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 26px;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
  }
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner p {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0px auto 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner .button {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  /* .homepage-banner .offers-banner .button a {
        color: #000;
      } */
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto 3em;
  }
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item img {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item:nth-of-type(2n) {
    margin: 0px auto 3.5em;
  }
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item:last-of-type {
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item img {
    width: 56%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .homepage-banner .offers-banner .offers-listing-container .item img {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="offers-banner">
  <picture>
    <source media=" (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/mobile/eyes-on-you-statement-banner-mobile.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/mobile/eyes-on-you-statement-banner-mobile_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
    <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="eyes-on-you-statement-banner-sp.jpg?$staticlink$?$staticlink$,images/home-page/smartphone/eyes-on-you-statement-banner-sp_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
    <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-statement-banner-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-statement-banner-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
    <img class="new-makeup-banner" alt="Eyes On You!" src="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-statement-banner-desktop.jpg?$staticlink$" srcset="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-statement-banner-desktop.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-statement-banner-desktop_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
    />
  </picture>
  <p>Twinkle, twinkle, you star! Transform your <br> holiday look with Juicy Couture Beauty. </p>
  <div class="offer-banner-content-wrapper">
    <div id="roll-over-collection-b" class="offers-listing-container">
      <div class="item">
        <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1502A0116919')$">
          <picture>
            <source media=" (max-width: 767px)" srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/mobile/mobile_eye_linner.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/mobile/mobile_eye_linner_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
            />
            <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_eye_linner.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_eye_linner_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
            />
            <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-1-hover-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-1-hover-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
            />
            <img id="hover-1" alt="Juicy Couture Oui Slay EyeLiner" class="rollover" src="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-1.jpg?$staticlink$ 1x"
              srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-1.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-1.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
            />
          </picture>
          <div class="item-name">
            <div class="button button-helper">SHOP NOW</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1502A0116950')$">
          <picture>
            <source media=" (max-width: 767px)" srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/mobile/mobile_EYE_TOPPER.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/mobile/mobile_EYE_TOPPER_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
            />
            <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/smartphone/SMARTPHONE_EYE_TOPPER.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/smartphone/SMARTPHONE_EYE_TOPPER_2X-.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
            />
            <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-2-hover-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-2-hover-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
            />
            <img id="hover-2" alt="Juicy Couture Lip + Eye Topper" class="rollover" src="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2.jpg?$staticlink$ 1x"
              srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-2.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
            />
        </a>
        </picture>

        <div class="item-name">
          <div class="button button-helper">SHOP NOW </div>
        </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1502A0116930')$">
          <picture>
            <source media=" (max-width: 767px)" srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/mobile/mobile_color_palette.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/mobile/mobile_color_palette_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
            />
            <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/smartphone/eyes-on-you-eye-liner-sp.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_color_palette_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
            />
            <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-3-hover-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-3-hover-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
            />
            <img id="hover-3" alt="Juicy Couture The Shady Color Palette" class="rollover" src="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-3.jpg?$staticlink$"
              srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-3.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-3.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
            />
          </picture>
          <div class="item-name">
            <div class="button button-helper">SHOP NOW </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bkgrd-img">
      <picture>
        <source media=" (max-width: 479px)" srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/mobile/updated_mobile_eyes_on_you_background.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/mobile/updated_mobile_eyes_on_you_background_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x "
        />
        <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/smartphone/updated_smartphone_eyes_on_you_background.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_eyes_on_you_background_2x-up.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
        />
        <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-background-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-background-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x "
        />
        <img alt="" src="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_background.jpg?$staticlink$" srcset="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_background.jpg?$staticlink$, https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dwd13910f1/images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_background_@2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x"
        />
      </picture>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. Sadly, IE9-IE11 support `let`, but **don't** support the correct ES2015 ("ES6") semantics for `let`. In particular, they **don't** create a new `i` for each iteration of the loop as ES2015 defines.

   To support IE, you'll have to use one of the other solutions shown in the answers to [the question linked in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), such using `bind` (IE9+):

   ```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     var rollOverCollectionA = document.getElementById("roll-over-collection-b").getElementsByClassName("rollover");
     rollOverCollectionA = Array.prototype.slice.apply(rollOverCollectionA);
     console.log("rollOverCollectionA", rollOverCollectionA);
     var l = rollOverCollectionA.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
       //     ^^^
       on("mouseover", "#" + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function() {
       console.log("mouseover " + this.id + " " + (typeof this.srcset));
         var srcObj = this.srcset.splice(171, 0, '-hover');
       // ------------^^^^
         srcObj.splice(362, 0, 'hover-')
         rollOver(this.id, srcObj);
         // ------^^^^
       }.bind(rollOverCollectionA[i]));
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       on("mouseout", "#" + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function() {
       console.log("mouseout " + this.id + " " + (typeof this.srcset));
         // remove the hovers
         rollOut(this.id, this.srcset.replace('-hover', '').replace('hover-', ''));
         // -----^^^^-----^^^^
       }.bind(rollOverCollectionA[i]));
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     }
   });
   ```

   It's a very subtle bug if you don't happen to know that late-model IE has this not-spec-compliant `let`. We generally expect that a keyword will either blow up the script entirely (if not supported) or work correctly (if supported). Sadly, that's not the case here.
2. The `srcset` property doesn't exist on IE, because IE doesn't support the `srcset` attribute. You'll need to manipulate `src` instead. (You could still access the `srcset` attribute as an attribute [via `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`], but the value you get/set is a string and IE won't use it).

Comment: Thanks my friend, I went with the solution above but added a `this` reference. Based on this answer from your link. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example#answer-19323214 

But I am still getting `Unable to get property "splice" of undefined or null reference`

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz - I've fixed the error in the code above for issue #1, and added issue #2. Sadly, supporting IE (even IE11) is getting increasingly painful as standards move on and IE doesn't.

Comment: Thanks you! So would I have to add a conditional for `srcset` if the browser supports it, and a fall back if it doesn't?

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz - Up to you. If you can do what you want to do with just `src`, then no need for the srcset branch, but if not then yes, `if (!element.srcset)` checks if it's not supported.